# Ponteiros com métodos, onde estou errando?

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Criando uma class que terá dois métodos um atribuir outro imprimir vetores com `public` e depois chamar esse método no `main`.

Consegui fazer até aqui com o método *baby steps*. Onde estou errando e o que eu tenho que fazer?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class vetor
{
 int v, tamanho,vetores;

 public:
 void atribuir(int *v, int tamanho){
    for (int i=0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        cout << "Digite um numero: ";
        cin >> v[i];
    }
 }

 void mostrar(void)
 {
    for (int i =0; i<tamanho; i++) {
        cout << "O numero "<< i +1 << " inserido for: "
        <<vetores[&i]<<endl;
     }
 }
};

int main(){
int tamanhos;
 //    vetor *varios_vetor;
//    varios_vetor = new vetor[tamanho];

cout << "Digite o tamanho do vetor: ";
cin >> tamanhos;
cout <<"Tamanho do vetor: "<< tamanhos << endl;

//vetor::atribuir(int i, int tamanho)
//vetor *varios_vetor;
//varios_vetor = new vetor[tamanhos];

//varios_vetor[tamanhos].atribuir(int *v, int tamanhos);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você declarou v (e vetores) como uma variável int e não como um ponteiro ou array de int.

Comment: Como assim cara ta falando int v; que não é vetor ?

Comment: Não, int v não é um vetor é apenas uma variável int. Talvez você queira dizer int v[] ou int *v. Ou, talvez, você esteja pensando em utilizar a classe vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como o intuito é inicializar o vetor e depois mostrá-lo, você poderia simplesmente passar os valores desejados para a classe, não precisando de nenhum parâmetro na declaração de seu método *atribuir()*:

```
#include <iostream.h>

using namespace std;

class Vetor
{
      int *vetor, tamanho; //Variáveis privadas que são acessadas pelos métodos da classe.

      public:
      Vetor(int t, int *v) //Construtor da classe.
      {
           vetor = v;      
           tamanho = t;            
      }              

      void atribuir(){
           for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
               cout << "Digite um numero: ";
               cin >> vetor[i];
           }
      }

      void mostrar(void){
           for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) {
               cout << "O numero " << i + 1 << " inserido foi: " << vetor[i] <<endl;
           }
      }
};

int main(){

    int tamanho;

    cout << "Digite o tamanho do vetor: ";
    cin >> tamanho;
    cout << "Tamanho do vetor: " << tamanho << endl;

    int vetorDeInteiros[tamanho]; //Vetor com o tamanho especificado.

    Vetor objVetor(tamanho, vetorDeInteiros); //Instanciando a classe Vetor e passando as variáveis declaradas para seu construtor.

    objVetor.atribuir();
    objVetor.mostrar();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Era na hora de chamar o obj que não tava entendendo! Faleu muito obrigado mesmo! Deu um luz ! Muito Obrigado mesmo!!

Comment: @user6361 Se a resposta te ajudou, marque como resposta aceita. Assim todo mundo que tiver o mesmo problema vai saber como você resolveu.